# Help needed to form a table

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I am trying to build a table in Latex for the layout shown below. I am not able to write the syntax. Can someone please help me out.

[image: table layout]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). What is exactly your problem here? Without  a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) of how far you go with tables, or some indication of what you know, we cannot guess what you do not know. Said that, a guess: maybe you should search about the commands `\multicolumn` and `\multirow`.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE! If you only need this shape of a table, you do not even need multirow, but you will need it if you want to fill in stuff that runs over more than one line. Please have a look e.g. [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) and consider the following as a welcome present.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{1.2cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & &\\
\hline
& & & & & &\\
\cline{1-4}
& & & & & &\\[1cm]
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that this site works as follows. If you have some TeX code and have a problem, you can ask a question using a so-called [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. This site is not a convert-screen-shot-to-TeX-code service, even though this sometimes works, especially when users are newcomers.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion it was very helpful. Yes, I want to fill in the table with the contents. How do I go about it??

Comment: @PratheekHb Just fill in the text (or whatever) between, before after the `&` signs, Just see what happens if you replace `& & & & & &\\ ` by `& X & & & & &\\ ` in the code.

Comment: I tried doing it. I have to write four words one below the other in column 6 and two words one below the other in column 7 with each word starting with a bullet point.

Comment: I have just posted a question, there you can see. Can you please help me out.

Comment: @PratheekHb I guess that you will have much better chances of getting an answer if you start filling something in my answer and use that as your MWE.